# Excel - error after request external data from my server

Tags: php, excel, rest

I created a simple php example of how to receive requests from Excel, but when I return the data, Excel says unable to connect.
My server response is a simple html text, my sniffer show the request and response.

[image: Sniffer]

In Excel, go to tab Data and select From Web option, enter the url to my server and press button Ok,
now excel request creditials, after enter credentials and press button connect, `Excel says: Unable to connect`, but my sniffer show response is ok.

[image: Excel request credentials]

Excel response:

[image: Excel message error]

`My simple php code:`

```php
<?php   

    //Get All headers
    $headers   =   getallheaders();

    //Simple html
    $response  =   file_get_contents('./html.txt'); 

    //Checks if authorization key exists
    if( isset( $headers["Authorization"] ) ) {

        //Encode with gzip
        $content        =   gzencode( trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $response ) ), 9);

        //My user example (Only for test)
        $default_user   =   "my_user";
        $default_pass   =   "my_pass";

        //Get user and password
        list( $user, $pass ) = explode( ':', base64_decode( substr( $headers['Authorization'], 6 ) ) );

        //Check if equals
        if( $user == $default_user && $pass == $default_pass ) {
            //User and Password OK

            //Set content encoding 
            header('Content-Encoding: gzip');

            //Type response and encoding
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

            //Content length
            header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $content ) );

            //Show content
            echo $content;

            //Set http status 200 Ok
            http_response_code( 200 );

            return;
        }else {
            //User or pass not equals
            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'); exit();
        }        

    }else {
        //Authorization key is not set
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'); exit;
    }
```

All the request and processing on the server is correct, except the return, excel requires something more and I don't know what it is.

Any idea how I can resolve this error ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen  -https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f3099495-eba9-4600-85c5-131257564c82/get-data-from-web-with-authentication-connection-error?forum=excel  ?

Comment: The error message in the Excel dialog box indicates you're supplying the wrong credentials, so it's probably this line that is at fault: `if( $user == $default_user && $pass == $default_pass )`. Have you tried disabling authentication in the script?

Comment: @TimWilliams, this seems to be really a problem with Excel, the link you sent shows that.

Comment: @kmoser, the error message in excel is false, authentication with credentials was successful. Even removing the "if" from line 23, as recommended by you, excel displays the same error.

Comment: @Duque In that case I would try the following: 1. Don't gzip the output, and remove the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. 2. Change your `Content-Type` header from `text/html` to something more appropriate, e.g. `text/csv` or `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Comment: @kmoser, It doesn't work because the response content is html.